# Equation of the plane passing through the point and containing the line

Tags: linear-algebra

I should find an equation of the plane passing through the point

$A=(1,2,-1)$ 
and containing the line:

```
2x - y + 5z + 3= 0;
x - 5y + 2z -1 =0;
```

So the line seems to have two equation, and I don't know how to find a single equation of the line. How can I describe the line or just find the plane? Should I transform the equations into one, or..?

Comment: The highlighted equations describe planes. The required line is the intersection of both planes.

Comment: @Peter, thanks, but could you suggest what should I do next? I should evaluate the line of intersection and then choose one of the given planes as an answer??

Comment: No, the intersection of the planes is the line lying in the plane you have to find.

Comment: If you have found the line in the parameter form, you can simply calculate the second direction-vector by subtracting any point of the line from the point A.

Comment: Hint : The intersection of the planes is : $$\pmatrix{-\frac{16}{9} \\ \frac{-5}{9} \\ 0}+s \pmatrix{-23 \\-1\\ 9}$$

Comment: @Peter thank you, but how did you evaluate it? What formula did you use? Im sorry for asking so many questions but I've been learning for 5 days straight and I still have no idea how to solve it, I'm lost.

Comment: I solved the linear equation system. First I set $z=0$ to get a special solution. Then, I calculated the general solution of the eqaution $\pmatrix{2&-1&5\\1&-5&2}=\pmatrix{0\\0}$. To get this, set $z=1$, calculate th e solution and multiply it with $9$ to avoid fractions. Then you have a vector with integer entries and the general solution is s times this vector.

Comment: Finally, subtract $\pmatrix{-\frac{16}{9}\\-\frac{5}{9}\\0}$ from $\pmatrix{1\\2\\-1}$ to get a second direction-vector and add t times this vector to the line I mentioned. This is the required plane.

Comment: If you multiply the second vector with $9$ , you get the final solution $\pmatrix{-\frac{16}{9}\\-\frac{5}{9}\\0}+s\pmatrix{23\\-1\\9}+t\pmatrix{25\\23\\-9}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Multiplying the 2nd equation by 2 and subtracting gives $z=-5-9y$, and then substituting back into either equation gives $x=23y+11$.

Therefore the line has parametric equations $x=11+23t, \;y=t,\; z=-5-9t$, so

$\vec{a}=\langle23,1,-9\rangle$ is a direction vector for the line.

Since $B=(11,0,-5)$ is a point on the line, $\vec{b}=\vec{AB}=\langle10,-2,-4\rangle$ is parallel to the plane.

Therefore $\vec{n}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ will give a normal vector for the plane.

Comment: @user94413 thank you very much, I followed every step and I got n = (-14, -2, -56). Is this the answer? I mean, the vector is the answer, or should I somehow evaluate a plane from it?

Comment: Note, that different representations are possible for the same line. So, what did you get for the line ?

Comment: @Pau This doesn't seem to be the right normal vector, since it isn't orthogonal to $\vec{b}$.  Once you find $\vec{n}=\langle a,b,c\rangle$, you can write the equation as $ax+by+cz=d$, and then find d using the given point A.

Comment: @Peter I got the same line you did (if that is what you were asking).

Comment: @user84413 thank you, i think i got it! i ended up with -14x -2y -56c -38 = 0  :) thanks!

Comment: This result seems to be wrong. The vector $\pmatrix{-14\\-2\\-56}$ is not orthogonal to the vector $\pmatrix{23\\1\\-9}$

Comment: @Pau I think you want $\vec{n}=\langle-22,2,-56\rangle$, so the equation will have the form $11x-y+28z=d$ (after dividing by -2).

Comment: Yes, this normal vector is right. And the constant is $d=-19$.

Comment: @user84413, alrighty, but how did you get it? I checked twice and I don't know what I did wrong... i just evaluated the cross product the way it should be done... :(

Comment: @Peter, man, how'd you get to it? I swear, I evaluated the cross product right and I got n the way i got...

Comment: What cross-product ? That of the direction-vectors ?

Comment: I did not use a cross product. I chose the parameter form, which is easier to get in this case.

Comment: @Peter the one a x b... i dont really know how else to explain it, it goes like (1 * -4 - (-9 * -2)), - (23 * -4 - (-9*10)), + (23 * -2 - (10*1))...

Comment: I mean, which vectors did you "cross" ?

Comment: @Pau I think you just need to check your numerical calculations, since you have it set up correctly.  (You could also replace $\vec{b}$ by $\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}$ to make the numbers smaller.)

Comment: @Peter a and b...

Comment: @user84413 i've checked my numerical calculations and everything seems to be right... i don't really know what im doing wrong :(

Comment: -4-18=-22, -(-92-(-90))=2, and -46-10=-56

Comment: @user84413 omg, alright. Thanks! I can't believe I made a mistake there, I kept adding -4 and -18 and ending up with -14... sorry. I'm too tired for this. Thank you so much again, you really helped me out, it means a lot to me! :)

Comment: You're welcome!